# Can we merge driver and drivers tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Before it gets too much to handle, can we merge driver and drivers tag?

[driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/driver) x 1243
[drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/drivers) x 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per suggestion [driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/driver) was syn'ed to [drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/drivers) being the plural form used by default.