# How to tag questions asking for drivers?

Tags: discussion, tags

[History](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3587/169736).

As part of making the tags useful and somewhat rational, I've found myself in a problem with the questions that asks how to install certain drivers. The problem is that *they have tried nothing* (apt-get, dpkg, etc.) and their problems are:

1. Don't find the drivers
2. Don't know how to install them
3. Even after installed they don't work

The second is easy since they only need the [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag, since they are installing software on Ubuntu. But then, how we should tag the 1 and 3 reasons? The 3 should be with a grain of salt since they might have installed correctly the drivers and it just need a nug with some unrelated program (CUPS, x/sane, xorg, etc.) so those need to be retagged with the correct one, but the first... I've racked my brain trying to come up with something useful but... nope, nothing.

Comment: They should tag it according to what they need drivers for.. We certainly don't need a "drivers" tag IMO.

Comment: @Seth so, burn also the drivers tag, noted.

Comment: @Braiam Re: burning the drivers tag. We have 4,415 questions tagged [tag:drivers]. Let's not start untagging them--or even telling people not to use that tag--until there is some community consensus that it's bad. Personally I don't see what's wrong with it. Having the [tag:drivers] tag for a post about drivers doesn't keep the post from having other tags. However, even if it's decided to get rid of [tag:drivers], let's wait for that to get *decided* first.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm not saying to remove the drivers tag. This question sprung when I was removing the epson tag [due this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7733/do-we-need-brand-manufacturer-tags) and noticed an incredible ammount of the questions that appears in the question (1, 2, 3) so, I was asking how to tag them.

Comment: I have since changed my mind about the drivers tag. I'm not so sure it is as bad as I thought, although I'm open to opinions.